# Dockerized Neo4j ignoring previous database

Tags: docker, neo4j

I'm using the official docker image for Neo4j, and attempting to get my local development database to load in the docker server - however it completely ignores everything.

Does anyone have a hint on how to get the dockerized neo4j to accept the graph from another database? They are both the same version, 3.0.3.

Here's my docker run command, the path is anonymised but pointing to the correct folder which was generated by the other database.

```
docker run \
  --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
  --volume=/the/neo4j/data/folder:/data \
  neo4j:3.0.3
```

Thanks for any good hints on how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend the following setting:

```
--env=NEO4J_dbms_allowFormatMigration=true
```

Otherwise the datastore will not be upgraded. See https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-30/ for details.